# Exception when setting the CellStyle property

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

In SL4 when setting the CellStyle for a DataGridTemplateColumn from code I get this exception:

MS.Internal.WrappedException: The type initializer for 'Missing template.  Cannot initialize System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn.' threw an exception.

The code looks like this:

```
grdMain.IsReadOnly = true;   
DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();  templateColumn.HeaderStyle = (Style)this.Resources["ImageColumnHeaderStyle"]; 

templateColumn.CellStyle = (Style)this.Resources["CellStyle1"];  // This causes the exception   

//templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["DataTemplate1"];  // This works!      

grdMain.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
```

The markup is quite simple:

```
<Control.Resources>

   <Style x:Key="ImageColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
    ...
   </Style>        

   <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1"> 
      <TextBlock>abcde</TextBlock>     
   </DataTemplate>       

  <Style x:Key="CellStyle1"  TargetType="sdk:DataGridCell"> 
   <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}">                 
</Setter>

  </Style>
</Control.Resources>

   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
       <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="413" Name="grdMain" Width="335" />
   <Grid>
```

Since the style does nothing but setting the template to DataTemplate1, I am really puzzled!

Why does it work when I set the CellTemplate from code but not when I set it through the CellStyle property?

Thanks

//Peter

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Comment: It must be something in CellStyle1 declaration because I've tried your code and it's working

Answer (score 1):

The `Template` property of any control takes a `ControlTemplate` not a `DataTemplate` as your code appears to be attempting.
This:-

```
<Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}" />
```

should be this:-

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}" />
```

Comment: Almost there, it's ContentTemplate (on the DataGridCell), not CellTemplate (which is on the DataGridColumn).